# Using Django DeleteView and getting a 404 after delete confirmation

Tags: python, django

After clicking on "confirm" in my organism_delete.html form, I used to be redirected back to the list of organisms (organism_list.html template) as specified in the view. But now I get a 404 error instead.

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
> URL:  http://localhost:8000/library/organisms/ABC1233/delete/post?csrfmiddlewaretoken=Rdk575IEp5bbvrriJ1szlYNjmq8V1DvuYzNWEWz07s78IJSal9foHdkvxwcimIEp
>
> Using the URLconf defined in itslibrary.urls, Django tried these URL
> patterns, in this order:
> admin/
> accounts/  [name='home']
> library/ organisms/ [name='organism_list']
> library/ organisms/new/ [name='organism_new']
> library/ organisms/ [name='organism_detail']
> library/ organisms//update/ [name='organism_update']
> library/ organisms//delete/ [name='organism_delete']
> ^media/(?P.*)$ The current path,
> library/organisms/ABC1233/delete/post, didn’t match any of these.

Two things that stand out to me is first that the error says it's a GET request, not a POST as the form specifies.
And second is why is it trying to get to .../delete/**post...**?

It might be important to know that I changed my model and added "Primary Key = True" to a unique CharField, and I've been modifying the rest of the app to match that. It may not be related because I can list the organisms and I can get to the delete page, I just can't submit it.

I don't know how to debug this, it seems to be hidden behind the Django magic, any guidance will be very appreciated.

Code below:

Models.py:

```
#Organism
class Organism(models.Model):
    genbank = models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    genus = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    species = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    strain = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    organism_sequence = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    fasta = models.FileField(upload_to='organism_fasta/', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.genus[:10] + ', ' + self.species[:10] + ', ' + self.strain[:10]
            
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('organism_detail', args=[str(self.genbank)])
    
#Motif 
class Motif(models.Model):
    organism = models.ForeignKey('Organism', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name= "motifs")
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = MOTIF_CHOICES)
    motif_sequence = models.CharField(max_length = 600)
    structure_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='structures/', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name[:10]
```

app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('organisms/', views.OrganismListView.as_view(), name='organism_list'),
    path('organisms/new/', views.OrganismCreateView.as_view(), name='organism_new'),
    path('organisms/<pk>', views.OrganismDetailView.as_view(), name='organism_detail'),
    path('organisms/<pk>/update/', views.OrganismUpdateView.as_view(), name='organism_update'),
    path('organisms/<pk>/delete/', views.OrganismDeleteView.as_view(), name='organism_delete'),
]
```

Delete View in views.py:

```
#Delete
class OrganismDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Organism
    success_url = '/library/organisms'
    template_name = 'library/organism_delete.html'
    login_url = "/login"
```

organism_delete.html template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <form action="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{organism.genus}} {{organism.species}} {{organism.strain}}?</p>
     <p>This cannot be undone!</p>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="confirm"/>
 </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `method="…"` of the form is `"POST"`, not the <s>`action="…"`</s>:

```
<form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{organism.genus}} {{organism.species}} {{organism.strain}}?</p>
     <p>This cannot be undone!</p>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="confirm"/>
 </form>
```

It might be better to work with [**`reverse_lazy(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) to determine the path of the `success_url`:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class OrganismDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Organism
    success_url = reverse_lazy('organism_list')
    template_name = 'library/organism_delete.html'
    login_url = '/login'
```

Comment: I didn't pick up at first that changing the method is what was wrong with the post and I only applied the reverse lazy change. You were absolutely right. Thank you very much.
Also shout out to the #django IRC channel folks that found the same fix.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `<form action="post" ...`, you are asking the form to "append `post` to the current URL, using a GET request, and go the endpoint with 'your data'".

*More details here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp*

I am not sure how will you manage to make the page call again the same page (maybe omit `action="..."`, but you should add (change) `method="..."`; from the implicit `method="get"`, make it a `method="post"` instead.

Without being a django connoisseur myself, it would be nice if you could "easily" teach django to listen to the `method="delete"` instead of `POST`, as it will make your API a tad more semantic.